# Stata replace " " with missing values

Tags: stata

I have a large Stata dataset. In some variables the data has been coded with `" "` (space) instead than with missing values.

Is there any way to loop through each element of the dataset and replace it with the correct value?

I need something like

```
for variable in all_variables:
   for sample in all_samples_of_variable:
       if sample == ' ' :
          replace sample with missing value
```

Comment: Please provide a sample for the input data and of the desired output.

Comment: You could read this into pandas using [`read_stata`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-stata-reader) , call `replace` for those values and output again `to_stata`

Comment: @EdChum Stata keep the data in a numerical and label format.  Can the to_stata  command keep the stata labels  ?

Comment: don't know you'd have to try, I have no experience of stata files

Comment: why this question has been down voted so much?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but many people here object to (1) questions without an attempt at real code (2) appearing to ignore comments and answers (e.g. you didn't respond to the request by @Tichodroma). Criteria for downvoting are (a) doesn't show any research effort (b) is unclear or not useful.

Comment: Two votes to close specified "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion over concepts here. The question is explicitly about Stata but the code looks little like Stata. In Stata an empty string `""` is regarded as a missing string. A string containing just a space or spaces is not an empty string; it's not often informative, but that's a human issue.

Note that this problem can only arise for string variables, so you need to work on those only. Taking you at your word that spaces always mean missing, then

```
 ds, has(type string) 

 qui foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
     replace `v' = "" if trim(`v') == "" 
 }
```

-- or almost equivalently use

```
     replace `v' = trim(`v')
```